# Is there any way to link a graph to any particular vertex of another graph (igraph)?

Tags: r, igraph

I want to join two independent graph by joining the node of Graph one to another

For example, I have two graph G & H

G = 1-3,1-5,5-9,5-21,21-22
H = 0-31,31-32,31-34,31-35,35-88

I want to link Graph H with Graph G, by joining the node 0 of Graph H to node 5 of Graph G

1-3,1-5,5-9,5-21,21-22,5-0, 0-31,31-32,31-34,31-35,35-88

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please find below one possible solution from your data using the `edge()` function of the library `igraph`.

**Reprex**

- **STEP 1: Building and visualizing the graphs `G` and `H`**

```r
library(igraph)

# Building the graph 'G'    
G <- graph(edges = c("1","3", "1","5", "5","9", "5","21", "21","22"), directed = FALSE)

#Building the graph 'H' 
H <- graph(edges = c("0","31", "31","32", "31","34", "31","35", "35","88"), directed = FALSE) 

# Visualizing the graph 'G'     
plot(G)
```

[image]

```r
# Visualizing the graph 'H'
plot(H)
```

[image]

- **STEP 2: Combining the two graphs `G` and `H` with edge `0-5`**

```r
# Building the graph 'Results'
Results <- G + H + edge("0", "5")

# Visualizing the graph 'Results'
plot(Results)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 5):

You can try `disjoint_union` + `add_edges`

```
> add_edges(disjoint_union(G, H), c("0", "5"))
IGRAPH 6cbfa1f UN-- 12 11 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c)
+ edges from 6cbfa1f (vertex names):
 [1] 1 --3  1 --5  5 --9  5 --21 21--22 0 --31 31--32 31--34 31--35 35--88
[11] 5 --0
```

Comment: Objectively, I think your solution is equally worth mine. So, I also upvoted your answer. Cheers.

Comment: @lovalery Neither of you have upvoted the question though, even though you both put in the time to write a complete answer ;-) If a question is worth answering and spending time on, is it not worth upvoting?

Comment: @Thomas BTW, since you regularly answer in the [tag:igraph] / [tag:r] tags, perhaps you are interested in contributing to this project: https://github.com/igraph/usability-benchmarks What's required is not dissimilar to answering questions here.

Comment: @Szabolcs Sorry that I forgot to upvote the question. Now it’s done  I will take a look at the project when available, thanks for the info.

Comment: Thanks for being so active and helpful in this tag! I also tend to forget to upvote questions when I'm too focused on the answer. Just trying to create a good atmosphere here :-) BTW since a few days ago you can install the development version of igraph 1.3 using `remotes::install_github("igraph/rigraph@master")` (assuming that you have the R development tools installed). It does take a few minutes to compile, but this version has lots of bugfixes and should be quite stable already.

Comment: @Szabolcs, yes, you are right. Sorry for that. I just upvoted the question. I will make sure to pay more attention to this in the future: it is now on my list of good resolutions for 2022 ;-) Cheers.